# function readRunningWorkOuts with completion in class HKManager (HKTutorial) is never executed in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, healthkit

I am trying out the HKTutorial which I downloaded from Ray Wenderlich (https://www.raywenderlich.com/89733/healthkit-tutorial-with-swift-workouts) and converted the source to Swift 3.0

I am puzzled by the behavior of the codes in viewWillAppear of WorkoutsTableViewController.

My version of viewWillAppear after conversion:

```
  open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     print("View will appear")
     healthManager?.readRunningWorkOuts({ (results, error) -> Void in
        if( error != nil )
        {
           print("Error reading workouts: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
           return;
        }
        else
        {
           print("Workouts read successfully!")
        }
        print("Really")
        //Kkeep workouts and refresh tableview in main thread
        self.workouts = results as! [HKWorkout]
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        });

      })
      print("viewWillAppear ends")
  }

  open override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     print(workouts.count)
     return  workouts.count
  }
```

and func readRunningWorkouts in class HKManager:

```
  func readRunningWorkOuts(_ completion: (([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> Void)!) {

     print("readRunningWorkOuts")
     // 1. Predicate to read only running workouts
     let predicate =  HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: HKWorkoutActivityType.running)
     // 2. Order the workouts by date
     let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
     // 3. Create the query
     let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(), predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
     { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

        if let queryError = error {
           print( "There was an error while reading the samples: \(queryError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        completion!(results,error as NSError?)
     }
     // 4. Execute the query
     healthKitStore.execute(sampleQuery)

 }
```

and the output shows:

```
View will appear
viewWillAppear ends
0
0
0
0
0
```

The value of workouts.count in func numberOfRows indicates that no record has been read.

Authorization is done and I have many running data in Health app.

Obviously, the statements between print("View will appear") and print("viewWillAppear ends") are never executed.

What have I missed? Is the code correct? Please enlighten. Thank you.

The project files can be downloaded at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2400869/HKTutorialFinalCode.zip

Comment: @TusharSharma I did. The function is never called. It would have executed the first print statement if it was called.

Comment: @TusharSharma   var healthManager:HealthManager?

Comment: @TusharSharma I have added a link to download my Xcode project file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the line 22 of WorkoutsTableViewController.swift to:

```
 var  healthManager:HealthManager = HealthManager()
```

And changed the line in func viewWillAppear:

```
 healthManager?.readRunningWorkOut( { (results, error) -> Void in
```

to:

```
healthManager.readRunningWorkOut( { (results, error) -> Void in
```

Now, it works.